# zbar cannot decode barcode

Tags: decode, qr-code, zbar

I have two images of the same barcode. When I use zbar library (or qrtools wrapper) to decode images of QR Codes, ImageScanner.scanner returns 0 for some of them. As an example, I cannot figure out why this first qr code cannot be decoded:
[image: not decodable QR code]

while the 2nd one can be decoded:
[image: working Qr code]

Below is the code I use for decoding. *Result* value is 0, for the first image, and 1 for the second one.

```
            import zbar
            from PIL import Image

            scanner = zbar.ImageScanner()
            # configure the reader
            scanner.parse_config('enable')
            # obtain image data
            pil = Image.open(filename).convert('L')
            width, height = pil.size
            raw = pil.tostring()
            # wrap image data
            image = zbar.Image(width, height, 'Y800', raw)
            # scan the image for barcodes
            result = scanner.scan(image) #Value is 0, -1, 1
```

Any feedback on how I can make the zbar decoder work for the 1st image?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was around shadow removal. Once the image was binarized and shadow was removed, zbar was able to decode it